# shell script for sorting dictionary backwards?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Hi I want to write a shell script that sorts a dictionary by comparing the words from the end of the word instead of the beginning whereby the dictionary is accessible from /usr/share/dict/words

```
e.g the input would be 

orange
media
monkey

and the ouput would be:
media
orange
monkey
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the text using rev, pipe it into sort and the pipe it into rev to get it back the right way

```
rev filename | sort | rev
```